# Does Dart support functional programming?

Tags: functional-programming, dart

Does Google Dart language allow for functional programming to occur? In particular, are the following features supported?

- functions stored as variables (references),
- functional currying,
- lazy parameters

Other features of functional programming?

It looks like Dart does not support immutable data.

Comment: Dart currently supports immutable data, there are `const` and `final` objects.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Dart has first-class functions and supports many functional programming constructs.  Here are some examples of assigning functions to variables and of a curried function:

```dart
main() {
  f1(x) => x * 2;         // Define the function f1
  var f2 = f1;            // Assign f1 to the variable f2
  print(f2(7));           // Feel free to call f2 like any other function

  add(a) => (b) => a + b; // Curried addition
  print(add(3)(4));       // Calling curried addition

  var add3 = add(3);      // Combining the
  print(add3(2));         //  concepts
}
```

As expected, this produces:

```
14
7
5
```

I don't believe lazy parameters are possible, and you already noted that there is clearly mutable data.

Comment: What is your opinion on fpdart and dartz?

Answer (score 9):

Depends on what you mean by "functional programming". Functions are first-class objects, which covers point 1, there is `Function.apply` which lets you implement currying yourself, so that covers point 2, but other than that, Dart isn't very functional (immutability -- no, referential transparency -- no, lazy evaluation -- no, what else have you -- probably also no).

Comment: Referential transparency is a function of good design, not always language (yes, it's sometimes forced). Point being, you can get 99.9% of the way there with good programming practices, like only using immutable objects etc.

Comment: I agree that you can write Fortran in almost any language out there, but that's not the point, is it? :-)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. One cannot write Fortran in any language out there, only in Fortran can you write Fortran. You're missing the point that even without compiler (or: language) support, you can guarantee referential transparency. It transcends language.

Comment: OK, so "you can write Fortran in almost any language out there" is an allusion to "Real Programmers Don't Use Pascal", if you didn't read it yet, I wholeheartedly recommend ;-) We can argue all day long about who is missing the point, but that's not much fun, so I'll just leave this here: indeed referential transparency is a property of a program (or parts of a program), no doubt about that. At the same time, it's useful to be able to tell if given programming language supports you in achieving it (= enforces it, plus maybe provides an escape hatch). I think we'll both agree that Dart doesn't.

Comment: There is lazy evaluation of an infinite list of startup names in one of the Flutter code labs which I just did with code that looks like: https://github.com/nyck33/flutterApress/blob/master/startup_namer/lib/main.dart  Tutorial name was startup name generator.

Comment: Immutability is actually supported by Dart, there are `final` and `const` objects

Comment: I haven't followed Dart for many years now, but if memory serves, `const` objects are compile time constants, so nothing you can build when your program is running and rely on its immutability. And `final` guarantees shallow immutability only -- you still have to follow discipline to get truly immutable objects.

Answer (score 6):

Small example about immutability:

```dart
class Point {
  Point(this.x, this.y);
  int x,y;
  int get sum => x + y;
}
class ImmutablePoint{
  final  int x,y, sum;
  const ImmutablePoint(x,y) :
    this.x = x,this.y = y,this.sum = x + y;
}

class SemiImmutablePoint {
  int _x, _y; // _ -like private but not access protected by the VM.
  SemiImmutablePoint(this._x, this._y);
  int get x => _x;
  int get y => _y;
}

void main() {
  List<int> li = [1,2,3,4,5];
  final List<int> immutableLi = const [1,2,3,4,5];
  li[1] = 10; //ok
  li = [6,7,8]; //ok
  immutableLi[1] = 10; //error because const
  immutableLi = [6,7,8]; //error because final
  var p = new Point(5,10);
  p.x = 10; //ok
  p.sum = 10; // error can't be directly mutated
  var p2 = const ImmutablePoint(5,10); // compile-time constant
  p2.x = 10; //error
}
```

You can use FP with the Dart or even languages without types or immutability like JS. it's just a style, it doesn't require native implementation in the language.

With the languages like Scala FP paradigms are normally implemented with the type system so it's more restrictive and harder to unintentionally breach. But at the same time  you require from the lib user specialized knowledge of really complex type system, sometimes category theory - otherwise it's really hard to benefit from knowing that this thing is "monad" or "monoid" or whatever.  I can use lists without  knowing that those are monads or really useful concept of "future" in Dart. When you implement FP without "type magic" it's often clearer and more accessible to grasp by an average developer. But at the same time having powerful type system can help compiler perform advanced code optimizations and enable better static code analysis.

[Category theory for JavaScript programmers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FkgOHvNAU8&list=PLwuUlC2HlHGe7vmItFmrdBLn6p0AS8ALX) - *Worth watching.*

**added:** Now collections have `UnmodifiableListView` `UnmodifiableMapBase` `UnmodifiableMapView`

Comment: "FP style doesn't make a lot of sense with the modern browser engines" ... what part does not gel exactly?

Comment: @EdwardGarson Last 4 years have shown that I was wrong :P

Comment: Wrong about what exactly?

Comment: @EdwardGarson About usefulness of FP style in browser code.  Tools like immutable-js, RxJS are build on top of FP foundations and provide useful abstraction over otherwise mutable environment. Sometimes they even can provide performance improvement like, for example, use of immutable data structures in React.

Comment: We are in agreement then. We had a language issue; "browser code" is not strictly clear to a native English speaker. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 5):

To your last point, immutability, see:

- https://github.com/google/built_collection.dart
- https://github.com/google/built_value.dart

which provide library and codegen support for immutable collections and "value types". These help bridge the gap between OO and functional programming, for example allowing inline "updates" to immutable values:

```
var node = new Node((b) => b
  ..left.left.left.right.left.right.label = 'I’m a leaf!'
  ..left.left.right.right.label = 'I’m also a leaf!');
var updatedNode = node.rebuild((b) => b
  ..left.left.right.right.label = 'I’m not a leaf any more!'
  ..left.left.right.right.right.label = 'I’m the leaf now!');
```

Where "node" and "updatedNode" are both immutable. More detail in this article: [built_value for Immutable Object Models](https://medium.com/dartlang/darts-built-value-for-immutable-object-models-83e2497922d4).

Answer (score 4):

It seems there is a more popular solution called [dartz](https://github.com/spebbe/dartz)

DARTZ

- Type class hierarchy in the spirit of [cats](https://typelevel.org/cats/), [scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) and [the standard Haskell libraries](https://wiki.haskell.org/Typeclassopedia)
- Immutable, persistent collections, including IVector, IList, IMap, IHashMap, ISet and AVLTree
- Option, Either, State, Tuple, Free, Lens and other tools for programming in a functional style
- Evaluation, a Reader+Writer+State+Either+Future swiss army knife monad
- Type class instances (Monoids, Traversable Functors, Monads and so on) for included types, as well as for several standard Dart types
- Conveyor, an implementation of pure functional streaming
- [Examples](https://github.com/spebbe/dartz/tree/master/example), showcasing core concepts

I couldn't understand how to use it but there are examples.

Answer (score 3):

A package that improves Dart FP experience further
https://github.com/vsavkin/fpdart

An open issue about tail recursion
https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=29

Answer (score 1):

You can use this package for function currying : https://pub.dev/packages/functional

It can increase code readablity also.

```
  int add(int a,int b) => a+b;
```

and now this function can be curried as below.

```
  final inc = add % 1;
  final dec = add % -1;

  print(inc(5)); // Same as add(1, 5);
  print(dec(5)); // Same as add(-1, 5);
```